# Cloud Firestore subcollection access

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When accessing subcollections, should one use code like this:

```
DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(userId)
          .collection('shoppingLists')
          .document(listName)
          .get();
```

or this:

```
DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('users/$userId/shoppingLists')
          .document(listName)
          .get();
```

?

I *prefer* the first style.  Do they translate to the same I/O?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in result.

Actually, you can even shorten the second one to:

```dart
DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .document('users/$userId/shoppingLists/$listName')
          .get();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the **[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):**

> **Every document or collection in Cloud Firestore is uniquely identified by its location within the database, and you can create a reference that points to it. For convenience, to access the Cloud Firestore hierarchical data model, you can create references by specifying the path to a document or collection as a string, with path components separated by a forward slash (/).**

Therefore, you can choose to use either of the two methods you posted earlier or  shorten it even further as @AndreyGordeev suggested. It's really up to you.